# Ambiguous match, found 10 elements matching xpath "//html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/a[2]" (Capybara::Ambiguous)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

My project was working fine before when I update the gems now it starts giving me this error for some xpaths

Comment: Please post more information, like your actual selector/test code and the HTML you're testing it on.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing by "update gems", you upgraded Capybara to 2.0. This requires more specific matches, as outlined in the [announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/C0O7nP2YG1A) by Jonas Nicklas:

> When finding and interacting with elements through methods such as `click_link` and `fill_in`, if there were more than one element which matched, previously Capybara would try to guess which one you meant. From now on, Capybara will raise an exception instead. For example, if you have two fields named "Password" and "Password confirmation", then `fill_in "Password", :with => "test"` will raise an exception.

The simple solution is to make your selectors [more specific](http://techblog.fundinggates.com/blog/2012/08/capybara-2-0-upgrade-guide/) by using CSS classes/IDs or more specific XPath instead of text labels.

Answer (score 1):

//html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/a[2] is very poor xpath that you usually get from using firebug. That's a total of 10 forward slashes which is very brittle. It is true that sometimes developers leave out ID's (and use css classes randomly) but if this is the case I'd recommend asking them to put ID's in.

This will alow you to go from

```
//html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/a[2]
```

to

```
//a[@id='id_2']
```

Much easier but it requires close team work with the developer

My advice would be to read the following article: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 0):

Eg: Given the attributes

Cucumber/capybara uses labels so change custome names for one of the lables like so;

<%= f.label :password_confirmation,**"Confirmation"** %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>